expect - repeatably send "\n\r" before a match expect
I need to netcat a U-Boot and perform NAND script and I use below script
spawn netcat -lup 6666
expect "Hit any key to stop autoboot" 
#autoboot counts down from 3 to 0 and somehow one or two send won't stop autoboot
for {set count 0} {$count < 30} {incr count} {
        send "\n\r"
        after 200      
}

expect "U-Boot >"
send "nand info"

Just need to repeatably send "\n\r" before "U-Boot >" shows up.
Is there a better way to do this?

I have very limited experience with expect, but I thought you only needed \r AND separately, that the traditional MS-Windows line ending is \r\n. It's worth trying those options to see if it solves your problem.

looks like "\n\r" is more effective than "\r". I just need the code to be more efficient. It gives me 4-5 redundant "U-Boot >" after 30 loops. I think there's a better way to replace the for loop.

Have you tried sending one or two space characters without carriage return or line feed?

Try a more programmatic way: send the LF-CR combo, and wait for the U-Boot prompt. If you don't see it after 1 second, send another LF-CR and wait again.
spawn netcat -lup 6666
expect "Hit any key to stop autoboot" 
#autoboot counts down from 3 to 0 and somehow one or two send won't stop autoboot
send "\n\r"
set timeout 1
expect {
    timeout {
        send "\n\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "U-Boot >"
}
set timeout -1    ;# infinite timeout
send "nand info"

